# Where should I store user's(not logged in) request data?

Tags: spring-boot, alert

I want to make an alert function in my side project where users set their custom limit(especially for cryptocurrency prices), and whenever price move beyond their custom limit, users get alert from my server.(It's almost like tradingview's alert function).
I managed to get price data by using websocket. What I'm concerned about is that **where should I store user's custom limit data?**
I want this feature to open everybody, not just logged-in user, so I think It would be very difficult to store all custom limit data in Database. OR should I use session to store data?? I'm making this project all by my self and got no one to ask.. could anyone give me any tips/ or references? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can store user's data on localStorage without login. This is a reference article on W3School : [link here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)